# How to use Soql query where condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

Hi i want help in soql query, i want the record that are multiple of 12 for `Age__c` number field. For example if record that has age field as 12, it should return the record, if 23 no record. How to achieve this?

```
SELECT Id, Name,Age__c FROM subtype__c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create list of integer with multiple of 12, And pass the list into SOQL"IN"

```
List<integer > ageList=new List<integer >();  
for(integer i=1;i<10;i++)
    ageList.add(i*12);

List<subtype__c> subtypes=[SELECT Id, Name,Age__c FROM subtype__c where Age__c in : ageList];
```